# Steam says I need some 32-bit libraries, but I don't know what to install

Tags: apt, ppa, steam, 32-bit

I am trying to use Steam right now. However, it constantly gives me the following error every single time:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpipewire-0.3.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libxcb-res.so.0
libvdpau.so.1
```

This only started recently and used to never be an issue. I don't know what caused this. I know how to fix it - install the libraries - however, I don't know what they're called in the Ubuntu PPA, or if they're even in the Ubuntu PPA.

System info:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- Mid-2012 MacBook Pro i5 13", modified to have 16GB RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through https://packages.ubuntu.com/ you are able to search the contents of all the packages that are installable through `apt install`, in the section "Search the contents of packages".

The codename of 22.04 is Jammy, so by using the following inputs:
[image]
I can see that this file exists in the package `libvdpau1`.

I believe if you do this for all the files listed you will be able to find all the missing packages for your system :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)